# Is core data migration necessary?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am making an app that will store scores (kind of like a quiz app) - I will  be playing around with core data and storing values to work out the best way to use core data. I know that if you start storing and fetching from core data and you then add/delete entities without migration, problems occur.

But, as I am only testing, I do not mind deleting the app of my device, and then reinstalling (which will cause me to lose data) - will this help me avoid the need of migrating (because when I download, it is seeing the new core data for the first time)

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is necessary in that case too. Otherwise xcode throw an error

Answer (score 0):

As you said "I do not mind deleting the app of my device, and then reinstalling (which will cause me to lose data)" so you **dont need migration** at all. Migration is needed when you have a already published app on appstore and you dont want to create a mess for people who have already installed your app.